# Is there any way in ARM Templates to use a Case-like statement?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

Is there any way in Azure to use a `CASE`-like statement depending on the value of a parameter or variable?

For instance:

```
    if vmName = "DB" then adminloginName = "DBAdmin"
    if vmName = "RDP" then adminlogonNAme = "RDPAdmin"
```

Answer (score 1):

**No**, ARM Template functions as of today **NOT YET support** Case like statements.

However, they do support the logical `if` function already.

> **Logical functions**
>
> Resource Manager provides the following functions for working with
>   logical conditions:
>
> - and
> - bool
> - if
> - not
> - or

Reference: [Azure Resource Manager template functions - Logical Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions#logical-functions)

Comment: Can you @4c74356b41 explain what exactly not true when the statement is quoted from official documentation?

Comment: because look at my example of a case statement, effectively

Comment: Your example does not generalize at all. What if eg Case if vmName = "DB" then adminloginName = "xxx" if vmName = "RDP" then adminlogonNAme = "yyy", then your example also break effectively

Comment: same will happen to your case statement, you can also work around that by creating allowed values for a parameter

Comment: I did not even try to use any case-like statement in my answer. All I say is it does not support today. It just shows that you are disapproving others for the sake of disapproving instead of helpfully correcting with some valid and convincing arguments.

Answer (score 0):

As @juvchan pointed out. There is no support for a CASE statement, though there is support for some logical checks.
To solve the problem you've described, however, you could use variables in conjunction with the parameters to construct the admin name. For example...

```
"parameters": {
   "vm_name": {
     "defaultValue": "DB",
     "type": "string"
},

"variables": {
   "admin_name": "[concat(parameters('vm_name'), 'Admin')]"
}
```

Then you can just use the `admin_name` variable down in the resource definition.

```
"resources":[
   {
      ...other resource properties
      "adminloginName": "[variables('admin_name')]"
   }
]
```

There are also some string manipulation functions ([Azure ARM string functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-string)), including a `substring` function so that if you have VM names that start with or end with **DB** or **RDP**, then you can use just the part of the name you need.

Comment: @4c74356b41 - How so? If I'm inaccurate, I'd like to correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can emulate that with this:

```
"variables": {
    "vmName": "DB" # this supposed to be parameter, but for brievity i'll use variable
    "adminloginNameDB": "DBADMIN"
    "adminloginNameRDP": "RDPADMIN"
    "adminlogin": "[variables(concat('adminloginName', variables('vmName')))]"
}
```

so in reality you would use it like this: `"[variables(concat('adminloginName', parameters('vmName')))]"`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but so far the is no way to do such approach, however, you can apply some workaround / hacks:

OPTION 1:

```
"variables": {
  "adminloginName": "[if(equals(parameters('vmName'),'DB'),'DBAdmin',   'RDPAdmin'  )]"
}
```

OPTION 2:

```
"variables": {
  "adminloginNames":["DBAdmin","RDPAdmin"],
  "adminloginName": "[if(equals(parameters('vmName'),'DB'),first(variables('adminloginNames'),last(variables('adminloginNames')  )]",
}
```

There are other many combinations

Answer (score 0):

You could emulate case statements with nested if statements like so.

```
"variables": {
    "subscription_id": "[if(equals(parameters('env'),'dev'), parameters('devsubscriptionid'), if(equals(parameters('env'),'uat'), parameters('uatsubscriptionid'), parameters('prodsubscriptionid')))]",
    "routeTables_rt_gdp_apim_dev_ne_001_externalid": "[concat('/subscriptions/', variables('subscription_id'),'/resourceGroups/RG-COM-FIREWALL-DEV-NE-001-test/providers/Microsoft.Network/routeTables/rt-gdp-apim-dev-ne-001')]"
}
```